# Loadrunner jmx as external resource to monitor

Tags: jboss, jmx, loadrunner

I have verified that it is possible to connect to a jboss node through jmx in jvisualvm using remote connection with a portnumber and user name and password. However wanting to add this jboss node as external monitor in LR controller there is no place to add i.e. username and password when setting up a remote UNIX monitor in loadrunner. When adding a UNIX resource and external measurement all I am asked is the name of the machine to add (in the wizard). 
Is it possible to add a jboss node as UNIX resource monitor in LR controller without sitescope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMX requires Sitecope as the monitoring foundation for LoadRunner.   Or, you can find some sort of JMX to SNMP bridge and then use the native SNMP monitor in LoadRunner.   Howeverm, even then the SNMP monitor in SiteScope is more mature.